# Theorem counter overwrites the (sub)section counter

Tags: theorems, counters, setcounter, newtheoremstyle

I have to change my counter level from 4 to 2 and now the theorems increase the section counter. I am using amsmath and amsthm packages, my old counter code is:

```
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,mathrsfs}
\theoremstyle{definition} % Defi style
\newtheorem{defi}[subsubsection]{Definition} % defi
\newtheorem{bei}[subsubsection]{Beispiel} % beispiel
\theoremstyle{theorem} % Satz style
\newtheorem{satz}[subsubsection]{Satz} % Satz = Theorem
\newtheorem{lem}[subsubsection]{Lemma} % lemma
\newtheorem{kor}[subsubsection]{Korollar} % korollar
\newtheorem{prin}[subsubsection]{Prinzip} % prinzip
\theoremstyle{remark} % bemerkung style
\newtheorem*{bem}{Bemerkung} % bemerkung
```

I would like to have the following count:

```
1 Chapter
  1.1 Section
    1.1 Definition
    1.1.1 Subsection
      1.2 Definition
      1.3 Theorem
      1.4 Example
      1.5 Definition
    1.1.2 Subsection
      1.6 Theorem
  1.2 Section
2 Chapter
  2.1 Theorem
  2.1 Section
...
```

The counter should be continuous and should not affect the chapter counter.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to double check your documentation. It's `\newtheorem{internaleName}[sharedCounter]{displayedText}[parentCounter]`.  With `\newtheorem{internaleName}[subsubsection]{displayedText}`, you're saying you want the theorem to share the same counter as the subsubsections, so that they get incremented with each use.

Instead, you want `\newtheorem{defi}{Definition}[chapter]`, so that the counter starts over with each chapter (and the numbering is `chapterNumber.defiNumber`).  Subsequent commands would then be `\newtheorem{bei}[defi]{Beispiel}` so that it uses the same counter.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot!